# Magento 2 - Store wise description very hard to manage

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, store-view

I have 1000s of products and there are 3 different stores.

Product descriptions are stored on store level. So everytime I need to update any description I have to update it on all store levels.

Is there any other way of update description that when I update on one store it will update on all other stores too?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make description attribute global.

1. Go to manage attribute `Store -> Attributes -> Products`
2. search for the **description** attribute
3. In  **Advanced Attribute Properties** set **Scope** to **Global**

By doing this description attribute will be same for all stores.

**Note: After doing this, you would not be able to update different descriptions on store level.**

Comment: Sounds good. let me try

Comment: Worked for me :)