# Frontend not displaying product changes

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend, products

**Magento 2.3**

After adding a sentence to the main description and adding information to the short description on the product pages of admin, these changes do not display in the front end.

I've flushed the cache and re-indexed the indexer.

Comment: May be description is set on store level, try to change store view and update description. And then check if it is updating on frontend

Comment: Where my content for product is it says 'Description' with [Store View] underneath. Is this what I'm changing?

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting your comment :) You need to check if it is working after changing to store level. check screenshot https://www.screencast.com/t/0Ey20XlbFIUt

Comment: This is what I see -https://www.screencast.com/t/fUqEweGCHfv. Its slightly different from the image you've shared.

Comment: Yes, select "Default store view", change description, run cache and indexing, and then check frontend

Comment: When I change to 'Default store view' I can't alter the content at all. I can't even get the cursor in the existing paragraph. When in 'Default store view' the 2 content description boxes have a 'Use default value' check box at the bottom of each box. This makes no difference if checked or unchecked.

Comment: Please follow this, see if it resolve your issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/273771/magento-2-store-wise-description-very-hard-to-manage/273772#273772

Comment: I followed the instructions in the link but I'm still getting the same problem. I seem to have the main description displaying on the frontend albeit I can't alter it but the short description will not display at all.

Comment: Update... I'm not sure if its the way magento is supposed to work but I can change the content for both the 'description' & 'short descrtiption' now. My products are configurable products and I can't change the content on each individual simple products created by the configurable product. But the content will change for the main configurable product.

Comment: Yes, it is how magento works, it show only configurable details on frontend. and simple products are just for prices, qty and variations

Comment: Does it matter how you input the SEO fields. For example is it only beneficial to provide SEO on the main configurable product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Description and Short Description will not display with a Simple Product created from a Configurable Product. The frontend will only display content that you input on the main Configurable Product.